# OpenGL ES drawing a 2D texture costs too much time.What is the reason?

Tags: android, opengl-es

My requirement is that there is a Camera preview using GLSurfaceView,and a picture of a png cover the GLSurfaceView as an overlay,then we will get a view which contains a picture above and Camera view below.

It is important that the cover above is updated per 30ms.The function of glDrawElements() will cast 150ms-200ms when the cover updating.Why the operation cost so much time?

The picture size I used is **480 * 300**.The sellphone is **Galaxy Nexus（I9250）** Android 4.3

Config Texture Objects,the pseudo code like this:

```
1.n=200,GLES20.glGenTextures(n, texture, 0); ;
2.for i=0:200 do GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,bitmap[i],0);
```

In onDrawframe() of Renderer of GLSurfaceView,procedure like this:

```
...
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(...);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(..);

GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(target,texture[index ++]);
/**
* The line costs so mush time when changing the Texture Object.
*/
GLES20.glDrawElements();
...
```

**Question:**

1.Why OpenGL ES costs so mush time when **changing Texture objects**? First drawing will cost 150ms-200ms,but drawing again just cost 1ms-3ms.

2.Is there any other memory mechanism held by OpenGL Texture?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
If I change the picture to size **240*150**,**100*100**,**64*64**,the time drops down to 3ms-5ms.I guss there is a suitable size to render which can get a good performance.But I don't know how to get the suitable size of rendering  of GPU.

Comment: What do you mean by `changing the texture objects`? Do you bind different textures between calls? And how exactly do you measure the time for `glDraw*` execution?

Comment: @Reaper Yes,I bind  different texture objects in every calls. I measure the time by `t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();  glDrawElements(); t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();`.